# Problem regarding bullet penetration

Tags: forces, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Which property remains constant when we say that bullets are penetrating the wall? I mean is the resistive force always constant for a given wall (assumed stationary and immovable) irrespective of the mass or velocity of the bullet ? Or the stopping time is constant and the force varies?

Comment: Constant w.r.t. to time? Or during different experiments? Mass and energy should always be conserved in this situation. But the force stopping the bullet will be higher, the higher its momentum. That is, either having more velocity or mass will increase its momentum, and this one is the relevant for the collision.

Comment: so you mean to say that for a given wall the stopping time will be same irrespective of the bullet mass or velocity? @rmhleo

Comment: The profile of the bullet will affect the retarding force as will the instantaneous velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Newton developed a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth) for penetration depth of projectiles traveling at high speed.

$$D\approx l_\text{bullet}\frac{\rho_\text{bullet}}{\rho_\text{wall}}$$

To a good approximation, the depth of penetration is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing that is constant is ***momentum*** in an inelastic collision. The force is constant for a specific wall and a *moving* bullet(considered to be appoint mass) irrespective of time.

But, since in this case you take the wall to be immovable then its only the force which is constant. As you may want to say that the momentum that Earth gets due to the hitting bullet is negligible.

Also, the force on the bullet may not be same for all velocities. Its a resistive force is similar to friction so you have kinetic as well as static friction. And you may also know that friction is a self adjusting force. So force is always constant- yes, but only when its greater than the optimum velocity, that is when kinetic friction acts.

Comment: You have conflicting statements. You say the force is constant for a specific bullet/wall set (I disagree), but then you say the force may *not* be the same for all velocities. So you agree with me that the force is velocity dependent. In that case, the retarding force is not constant because the velocity of the bullet is changing as it slows. Your last sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, ok, if you are thinking like that @BillN

Comment: Till the bullet is moving inside the wall, force is constant. I meant that @BillN

Comment: Are you talking about gravitational force?  That's not in the picture of the OP question. Neither is air resistance. The only force pertinent here is the retarding force from the wall on the bullet which reduces the bullet momentum to zero w.r.t. the wall (unless it comes out the other side).

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the retarding force of the wall, that's constant till bullet is moving inside the wall @BillN

Comment: I'd like to see you expand your answer to justify this. The retarding force is going to depend on the shape of the bullet (hollow point vs round point vs sharp point) and the total cross-sectional area of interaction. Bullets aren't flat faced.

Comment: I don't think the OP bothers about the geometry of the bullet. I have considered it to be a point mass, see edit@BillN